# ASN.1 type 0x80

Tags: asn.1

My ASN.1 decoder was working fine up until I faced an interesting type:

`0x80` which was decoded by online tools as a simple type with name `[0]`.

I found some sources mentioning this to be "indefinite length", but it definitely had a definite length which I could read. What actually is this type and are there other types like that?

Comment: It depends on where `0x80` is presented in a TLV structure. If this value is presented in type (tag), it is type selector (choice). If this value is presented in length, then it denotes indefinite length. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Crypt32 Yes, it is a type (tag), sorry if i was unclear

Comment: Then this is implicit type selector (choice) without outer type and underlying data type is simple type.

Comment: @Crypt32 is it what was described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30608283/7343355)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a tag, `0x80` (under BER, CER, or DER) means a tag whose class is context-specific (vs the named classes, `UNIVERSAL`, `PRIVATE`, and `APPLICATION`), whose number is `0`, and whose encoding is primitive.  The fact that it is primitive means it is being used as an `IMPLICIT` tag.  Had it been `0xA0` (Constructed, Context-Specific 0) it could be either an `EXPLICIT` tag (a wrapper) or an `IMPLICIT` constructed value (`SEQUENCE`, `SEQUENCE-OF`, etc).

Knowing what such a value means require looking at the ASN.1 type definition.

For example, from [RFC 3280 A.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#appendix-A.2) (`DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS`):

```
PrivateKeyUsagePeriod ::= SEQUENCE {
     notBefore       [0]     GeneralizedTime OPTIONAL,
     notAfter        [1]     GeneralizedTime OPTIONAL }
```

If a `PrivateKeyUsagePeriod` had a `notBefore` value then it would be tagged with `0x80` (`[0]`) instead of `0x18` (`[UNIVERSAL 24]`); but it should still be interpreted following the encoding for `GeneralizedTime`.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify the part "whose number is 0" - does this mean that [1] would be 0x81?

Comment: @karolyzz Yep.  [X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.690-201508-I!!PDF-E&type=items) section 8.1.2 ("Identifier octets")